# Visual Studio 2019 Windows SDK executable path macro has multiple paths

Tags: visual-studio, macros, post-build-event, build-events

I'm trying to use `$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64)` in my C++ project post build events to copy some files. However, it contains two paths instead of one. I can't seem to be able to find how to use the first path (not the .Net one):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64
```

I'd like to do something like `copy /Y $(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64)\bin\file.ext destination` in my post build events. How can I do this? I'm using VS 2019 and have the latest Windows SDK installed.

Comment: `WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64` is the path to the build systems.  Just like the PATH environment variable.  Also copying part of the tool-chain seems strange to me. What are you trying to achieve? Feeling like an XY-problem.

Comment: I need to copy dxcompiler.dll and dxil.dll to the executable if it's not already there or a new version is available. setting a path is not enough since I need to redistribute those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following:

`$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\$(TargetPlatformVersion)\x64\dxil.dll`